# postgres connection refused in swing

Tags: java, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am getting error while connecting to remote machine , here is the java error log -

```
DBConnection.getConnectionFromDB - Error Occured -- SQL EXCEPTION
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:207)
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:136)
at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31)
at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:397)
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

and here is pg_hba.conf file -

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             192.168.1.101/24        trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: is the server running? Is the username/ password correct?

Comment: @ScaryWombat : Yes postgres service is running, and username passwords are correct.

Comment: @MadProgrammer : I have tried by disabling firewall, it does not work. Should I provide java code? 
What I am trying to achieve is to access the database via executable jar, database machine is alloted ip 192.168.1.101, others are not alloted any ip, they will fetch it via DHCP.

Answer (score 0):

First, check the value of parameter [listen_addresses](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-LISTEN-ADDRESSES) in the postgresql.conf config file. If not set, then the database engine would only accept connections via local Unix sockets, and would not listen on any TCP/IP port.

After this, confirm that you can use the command line tool psql to connect to the database from the client machines.

If you cannot achieve this, and assuming that the machines have ip contact (ie, you can ping the server from the client) then it implies a firewall, either on the client, on the server, or some intermediate switch or router.

If you do manage to connect via psql, then check the connection parameters you have used in the jdbc connection string, particularly the address/hostname and port numbers.

Oh, and BTW, the two lines you have in pg_hba.conf ending in 'trust' are a spectacularly bad idea. They mean that anybody on any machine can connect without supplying a password or any other credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Solved 
Do following

**Update** : `/var/lib/pgsql/<version>/data/postgresql.conf`

**change** : `#listen_addresses = 'localhost' to listen_addresses = '*'`

**restart service**